# How to set attribute for nodes with text content?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to iterate over set of nodes given by xpath and set certain attribute for each node. However it works only for nodes withou content or with empty (whitespace) content. I have tried 2 approaches but with the same result (maybe they are both the same on some deeper level, dunno). The commented line is the second approach.

```
$temp = simplexml_load_string (
'<toolbox>
    <hammer/>
    <screwdriver>   </screwdriver>
    <knife>
        sharp
    </knife>
</toolbox>' );

echo "vanilla toolbox: ";
print_r($temp);

$nodes = $temp->xpath('//*[not(@id)]');

foreach($nodes as $obj) {
    $tempdom = dom_import_simplexml($obj);
    $tempdom->setAttributeNode(new DOMAttr('id', 5));
    //$obj->addAttribute('bagr', 5);
}

echo "processed toolbox: ";
print_r($temp);
```

This is output. Attribute id is missing in node knife.:

```
vanilla toolbox: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[hammer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[screwdriver] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] =>    
    )

[knife] => 
        sharp

)
processed toolbox: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
    )

[hammer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
            )

    )

[screwdriver] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
            )

        [0] =>    
    )

[knife] => 
        sharp
```

Comment: Why use `$tempdom->setAttributeNode(new DOMAttr('id', 5));` instead of `$tempdom->setAttribute('id', 5);`? Anyway, the code seems correct. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: It seems like a bug in my version. As I said below I am using PHP Version 5.3.8-pl0-gentoo and libxml Version 2.7.8.

Comment: Note that the way you are setting the attribute is much more complicated than it has to be. You can simply do `foreach($nodes as $obj) { $obj['id'] = 5; }`. Also note that unless you are using a DTD or Schema defining the id attribute to actually be an ID type attribute, your id attribute will just be a generic attribute and not considered for any IDRefs. Also see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/

Comment: Thanks, I know this way too, but wanted to explicitly show which functions are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce what you describe, the changed XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<toolbox id="5">
    <hammer id="5"/>
    <screwdriver id="5">   </screwdriver>
    <knife id="5">
        sharp
    </knife>
</toolbox>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DgqTH8)

It's exactly your code, maybe you're using a different LIBXML version? See the `LIBXML_VERSION` constant (codepad viper has 20626 (2.6.26)).

But probably it's just only the `print_r` output for a `SimpleXMLElement` object.

It does not output the attributes for the last element, even on a brand new object, but it's still possible to access the attribute. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/URcnMk).

You will see when you `print_r($temp->knife['id']);` that the attribute is set (as you can see in the earlier XML output).

Comment: Actually, your demo code *does* reproduce it. It gives `[knife] => sharp` in the dump, e.g. w\out the id attribute. It doesnt list knife as a SimpleXmlElement. Serializing it into XML again works though.

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.3.8-pl0-gentoo and libxml Version 2.7.8.

Comment: @Jan when you do `print_r($temp->knife);` you will see that the dump for the knife SimpleXmlElement contains the id attribute. I have no clue why `print_r($temp)` will only do `[knife] => sharp`. But then again, I wouldnt bother about dumping DOM or SimpleXmlElement instances. They are known to be quirky in dumps due to the way they expose their internals.

Comment: OH MY GOD! You are absolutely right! I suspected output may be incorrect but solved it only by trying both print_r() and var_dump(). You hit the nail on the head. How could I mark your comment as the most relevatn answer?

Comment: This is probably a defect of `SimpleXMLElement` in combination with `print_r`, it just does not output attributes on the last element (`<knife>` in your case). I added another demo to the answer, that just is a chunk of XML with the attributes set. Accessing with `$temp->knife['id']` does work however. Probably a bug/defect?

Comment: @hakre i'd say its just simplexml being simplexml ;P

Comment: In my case the absence of attributes in output was not related to node position but to the node content. Do you guys have any clue where exactly should I try to fill the bug report? PHP or libxml project?

Comment: I guess it's a flaw in PHP's SimpleXMLElement. However as `print_r` of `SimpleXMLElement` is not specified in any way, I don't know if it qualifies as an actual flaw. It might not just work as you expect it to work, so probably create a feature request.